# is it possible dynamically post files using tsung?

Tags: erlang, load-testing, tsung

i am planning to post dynamic files,

```
<request subst="true">
<http url="/test.php" contents_from_file="file.csv" method="POST"></http>
</request>
```

is there any option to post dynamic files instead of hard coded one ?

Answer (score 0):

The contents_from_file arg not support dynamic. 
please see the ts_config_http.erl file line 58.

You can also refer to this way:

```
    <if var="Args" eq="1">
      <request subst="true">
        <http url="/test.php" contents_from_file="1.csv" method="POST"></http>
      </request>
    </if>

     <if var="Args" eq="0">
      <request subst="true">
        <http url="/test.php" contents_from_file="2.csv" method="POST"></http>
      </request>
    </if>
```